# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Eloquent' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a script

```
<?php

    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    Dotenv::load(__DIR__);


    use \App\VSE, \App\User;
    // use Eloquent;

    $accounts = VSE::account_all();
    $accounts = json_decode (json_encode ($accounts), FALSE);

    foreach ($accounts as $account) {

        $user = new User;
        $user->id = $account->account_id;
        $user->account_id = $account->account_id;
        $user->email = $account->email_address;
        $user->auto_provisioning = null;
        $user->service_plan = null;
        $user->fb_email = '';
        $user->tw_email = '';
        $user->fb_access_token = '';
        $user->fb_profile_id = '';
        $user->fb_page_id = '';
        $user->fb_username = '';
        $user->save();
    }

?>
```

---

I kept getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/portal/app/User.php on line 6

---

How do I avoid that ?

Comment: Typically by defining and registering an autoloader. In this case, what are the contents of `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/app/User.php`? My guess is that whatever namespace contains the 'Eloquent' isn't specified inline or using a `use` statement

Comment: Can you please show me how do I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the User model is using Eloquent.

Are you trying to use Eloquent in a standalone app? There is some setup required in order to do this... see example here:

https://github.com/illuminate/database

What is in your composer.json?